# Select a group of elements and text using css selectors

Tags: css, scrapy, css-selectors

I have an HTML page like:-

```html
<div>
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
</div>
```

I need to select a group like this:-

```html
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
text
<br>
```

I need to select 3 values from a group:- link, name, and text.
Is there any way to select a group like this, and extract these particular values from each group in scrapy using, CSS selectors, Xpath, or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy provides a mechanism to `yield` multiple values on the html page using `Items`- as items, Python objects that define key-value pairs.

You can extract individually and but yield them together as key-value pairs.

- to extract value of an attribute of an element, use attr().
- to extract innerhtml, use text.

Like you can define your parse function in scrapy like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
      
        for_link = response.css(' .row.no-gutters div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(8)  a::attr(href)').getall()
            
        for_name = response.css(' .row.no-gutters div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(8) a u::text').getall()
              
        for_text =  response.css(' .row.no-gutters div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(8)::text').getall()
             
            # Yield all elements
            yield {"link": for_link, "name": for_name, "text": for_text}
```

Open the items.py file.

```
# Define here the models for your scraped
# items
# Import the required library
import scrapy
 
# Define the fields for Scrapy item here
# in class
class <yourspider>Item(scrapy.Item):
     
    # Item key for a
    for_link = scrapy.Field()
     
    # Item key for u
    for_name = scrapy.Field()
     
    # Item key for span
    for_text = scrapy.Field()
```

for more details, [read this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-scrapy-items/)

Comment: Hi, in my provided example, 'text' is not in <span>, so I guess this will not work, can you answer in case the 'text' is not in <span>?

Comment: Hi @Vishnu, try it now and feel free to ask any further questions :)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, but, the above code does not works as in my case 'name' is inside <a> but both 'text and <a> are inside <div>, so to select 'text' maybe would need to do like 'div *::text', but this also does not work as it will get 'name' again, and also gets '\n' for some reason, maybe from <br>

Comment: can you share the website, you are trying to scrape? I will share code accordingly.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply (power outage), I am trying to scrape `https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/r4ayzg7/mairimashita-iruma-kun` here in this page, I want to get "Related Series" section

Comment: Hey Vishnu, It's working now. Check the code. Let me know, if you need any further help on this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246360/discussion-between-neha-setia-nagpal-and-vishnu).

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay to wrap text in a span like so:

```
<a href='link'>
<u class>name</u>
</a>
<span>text</span>
<br>
```

Then you can select everything in CSS like so:

`a, a + span {}`

Or you can style these two separately:

`a {}`
`a + span {}`

The `+` means "comes immediately after" or "is immediately followed by".

Comment: Sorry @Sam, but I do not own the HTML, I just receive the HTML in the specified format